# Get value of shiny event

Tags: r, shiny

I want to access value of `Shiny.setInputValue( )` in javascript. In chrome console I tried `$('#too').length` and `document.querySelector('#too').innerHTML` but it does not capture the shiny event.

Note : I don't want value of shiny output. I know `document.querySelector('#table').innerHTML` returns value of too

```
library(shiny)  
ui <- fluidPage(      
  HTML('<script>
       $( document ).on("shiny:sessioninitialized", function(event) {
            Shiny.setInputValue("too", "noone");
       });</script>'),         
  textOutput("table")      
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderPrint(input$too) 
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but nevertheless.

You are already providing the value of `Shiny.setInputValue()` in javascript. So why don't you declare a variable like this:

```
library(shiny)  
ui <- fluidPage(      
  HTML('<script>
       $(document).on("shiny:sessioninitialized", function(event) {
       var inputValue = "noone"
       console.log(inputValue)
       Shiny.setInputValue("too", inputValue);
       });</script>'),         
  textOutput("table")      
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderPrint(input$too) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear. This is more for learning. I have a big JS from R package which triggers event via Shiny.setInputValue( ). I don't want to customize that package. Instead I want JS to listen when Shiny.setInputValue is triggered. I can do in R via input$too but want to do it in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may save it into a global variable instead:

```
library(shiny) 

js_set <- "$(document).on('shiny:sessioninitialized', function(event) {
        too = Math.random();
        Shiny.setInputValue('too', too);
})"


js_get <- "$(document).on('shiny:value', function(event) {
        console.log(too);
})"


ui <- fluidPage( 
    tags$script("var too = 0;"),
    tags$script(js_set),
    tags$script(js_get),
    textOutput("table")      
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderPrint({
        req(input$too)
        input$too
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to trigger an event whenever you set an input value:

```
function setInputValue(name, value) {
  Shiny.setInputValue(name, value);
  $('body').trigger('myevent', [name, value]);
}
```

Then you can listen to this event:

```
$('body').on('myevent', function(event, name, value) {
  // do something with name and value
});
```

Example:

```
js <- "
function setInputValue(name, value) {
  Shiny.setInputValue(name, value);
  $('body').trigger('myevent', [name, value]);
}
$('body').on('myevent', function(event, name, value) {
  console.log('name:', name);
  console.log('value:', value);
});
$(document).on('shiny:sessioninitialized', function() {
  setInputValue('too', 'hello');
});"


ui <- fluidPage( 
  tags$script(HTML(js)),
  verbatimTextOutput("table")      
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- renderPrint({
    input$too
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```